# execute cron jobs when .htaccess login protected?

Tags: htaccess, cron

My client is not able to execute cron-jobs in his wordpress dashboard because he gets 401 not authorized.

This is because he has an .htacess file blocking normal access to the site (it's a member site) and you have to add username and password to login.

Members are added by adding memberlogins to his .htacess file through another billing site (when a visitor has payed it he/she gets added to the .htaccess)

**Is there any workaround for this so .htaccess so may execute cron-jobs?** I don't actually know what the cron jobs do, but they seem to delete transient data etc.

Comment: Have you considered disabling WP Cron and using WP CLI's cron subcommand instead to trigger the events?

Comment: I've actually not considered anything. I wanted to know how to solve the issue and I think your sugesstion seems good but I'm not sure the hosting company allows me to do so (GoDaddy).